# Drupal: Add two cck fields dynamically and populate third with their sum

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have three cck fields.  Let's call them:

- Field A
- Field B
- Field C

I would like Field C to automatically be populated by the sum of Field A and Field B.  That, or the sum to be displayed somewhere within the form.

I guess I could do this using some jQuery, but I'm wondering if there is a Drupal specific way I should do it.

I looked high and low, but I'm still not sure of the best way to do it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Computed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field).  It will allow you to do exactly that.

From the project page:

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK
>   field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your
>   content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you
>   define via PHP code. You may draw on
>   anything available to Drupal,
>   including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it.
>   (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You can
>   also choose whether to store your
>   computed field values in the database
>   with other content fields, or have
>   them "calculated" on the fly during
>   node views. (Although you should note
>   that Views use requires database
>   stored values.) This field is
>   literally the Swiss Army knife of CCK
>   fields. So start cooking up your PHP
>   based values!

See the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/126522) for configuration examples and other helpful hints.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate C from A and B in the node_load() hook ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6 )